# iOS 9 Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I recently upgraded to Xcode 7. And my code that was working fine on 6.3 and iOS 8.4 now will not compile with a segmentation fault.

I am using Stephencelis library of SQLite. It seems to be causing the problem.

I would appreciate any help, any ideas.
Below is the last part of the error msg:

1. While type-checking getter for columnNames at /Users/luben/Downloads/SQLite.swift-master/SQLite/Query.swift:740:22
2. While type-checking declaration 0x7fbab3ee2d68 at /Users/luben/Downloads/SQLite.swift-master/SQLite/Query.swift:740:51
3. While type-checking expression at [/Users/luben/Downloads/SQLite.swift-master/SQLite/Query.swift:740:51 - line:774:7] RangeText="{
       var (columnNames, idx) = (String: Int, 0)
       column: for each in self.query.columns ?? [Expression(literal: "*")] {
           let pair = each.expression.SQL.characters.split { $0 == "." }.map { String($0) }
           let (tableName, column) = (pair.count > 1 ? pair.first : nil, pair.last!)

   ```
       func expandGlob(namespace: Bool) -> Query -> Void {
           return { table in
               var query = Query(table.database, table.tableName.unaliased)
               if let columns = table.columns { query.columns = columns  }
               var names = query.selectStatement.columnNames.map { quote(identifier: $0) }
               if namespace { names = names.map { "\(table.tableName.SQL).\($0)" } }
               for name in names { columnNames[name] = idx++ }
           }
       }

       if column == "*" {
           let tables = [self.query.select(*)] + self.query.joins.map { $0.table }
           if let tableName = tableName {
               for table in tables {
                   if table.tableName.SQL == tableName {
                       expandGlob(true)(table)
                       continue column
                   }
               }
               assertionFailure("no such table: \(tableName)")
           }
           tables.map(expandGlob(self.query.joins.count > 0))
           continue
       }

       columnNames[each.expression.SQL] = idx++
   }
   return columnNames
   ```

   }()"

Answer (score -1):

The SQLite.swift project on GitHub provides a [Swift 2 branch](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/swift-2). It probably solves the problem.